# Removing entire entry if line is less than an amount desired

Tags: windows, excel, shell

I have a long list made up of text like this

```
Email: example@example.com
Language Spoken: Sample
Points: 52600
Lifetime points: 100000
Country: US
Number: 1234
Gender: Male
Status: Activated
=============================================
```

I need a way of filtering this list so that only students with higher than 52600 points gets shown. I am currently looking at solutions for this, I thought maybe excel would be a start but am not too sure and wanted input.

Comment: How is the list set up in cells?

Comment: a shell script would be easier, or a text editor with regex.

Comment: How would this be done with regex?

Comment: Are the number of lines consistent between each entry? If they are you can just do a `.find(what:='Points: '`, extract the number after and if it is not higher than your set limit you can delete from your found range using `offset(cell(0,-2),cell(0,6)` then move on to the next `.find` until no more are found. Hope this helps you on your way.

Comment: Hm, couldn't exactly get it to work, I did =find(what:='Points: ' as instructed but it always gave me back an error. How would this be done in a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Excel:

1) Copy Text into Column A

2) In B1 enter "1", then in B2 enter the formula: `=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="=",B1+1,B1)`, then copy that down to the end.
(This splits the text into groups divided by the equal signs)

3) In C1 enter the formula: `=IF(LEFT(A1,8)="Points: ",VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-8)),0)`, then copy that down to the end.
(Basically this is populating the points in column B)

4) In D1 enter the formula: `=SUMIF(B:B,B1,C:C)`, then copy that down to the end.
(This just sums the amounts in column B by grouping)

5) Finally put a filter on Column D, and filter by greater than or equal to the amount desired.

Comment: Hi, is there anyway to stretch the formula faster down the list? The list I have contains 56600 lines so dragging isn't the best.           

                           

I have tried to select them all but the formula doesn't go with all of them (ctrl+a)

Comment: Try the following: Select `C1:D2` and hit `Ctrl+D`, then select `B2:D56600` and hit `Ctrl+D` again.